# Reference/notes for introduction to (von Neumann) architecture

Tags: computer-architecture, reference-request

I am interested in understanding what we mean by a von Neumann architecture and need something at a very introductory level. Does anyone know of any good and readable references or notes that will introduce me to this topic?

Comment: What research have you done?  It's explained in many standard resources, including Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann_architecture), probably many standard textbooks, and I imagine a websearch will turn up a lot of material as well.  We expect you to do a significant amount of research before asking here.  There's not a lot of value in us repeating material that is already widely available in standard resources.

Comment: Recommendation questions often don't work out very well here, as they can easily devolve into an opinion poll.  See our [help/dont-ask].  Some advice for making them work well: identify specific criteria or requirements; do some research to identify what candidates you can find, show them in the question, and explain why they did not meet your criteria.  In this case, it's not clear what counts as "very introductory", and "good" and "readable" are a matter of opinion.